# Worker Service in a Microservice Architecture

Tags: microservices

Soon I'll start a project based on a Microservice Architecture and ones of the components I need to develop is a Worker Service (or Daemon).

I have some conceptual questions about this.
I need to create a worker service that send emails and sms. This worker service need the data to send this emails. Also, I need to create a micro service that allow users to create a list of emails that need to be sanded by this Worker service. But both of then need to consume data from the same database.

In my worker service I should consume a micro service resource to get the data or it's ok that this worker service have a connection to the same database that my micro service?

Or is best that my worker service also has the api endpoints to let the users create new lists of emails, add or modify configuration and all the other functionalities i need to implement? This sound like a good idea, but I'll get a component with two responsibilities, so I have some doubts about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you added worker services functionality to the microservice, you need to put some weight on handling concurrency of the service. Because single microservice can have multiple instances. That doesn't mean it is a bad idea!

Comment: Yes, you're right, is possible to implement some load balance to the Microservice.

Answer (score 1):

Two microservices sharing the connection to the same database is usually a bad idea. Because each service should be the owner of its own data model and no one else should access it directly. If a service needs data of the domain of another service it should get it calling the owner via API or replicating the model in a read-only way in its own dabase and update it using events for example.

However, I think that for your current use case the best option is to provide the worker with all the information that it needs to send an email, (address, subject, body, attached files...) so the only responsibility of the worker will be to send emails and not to fetch the information.

It could provide also the functionality to send emails in batches. In the end, the responsibility of the service will be only one "To send emails" but it can provide different ways to do it (single emails, batches, with attached files... etc)

Comment: Thanks. And you're right, I'm only using the worker for sending emails, nothing else, so I'll take your advice and connect a microservice and this worker to the same database. Thanks again.

Comment: how you control that multiple instances of workers are working on a different set of data?